are there Best practices for modifying a controlling owner BO (custRelMod) with fincen enabled on business client (silverLake)
During BO maintenance. ie when changing the cntlOwner on a business Client. We are seeing an error 402066 (This Customer's FinCEN Legal Entity flag is set to "Include", A Controlling Owner is required from silverLake.) when trying to remove a cntlOwn in order to add the new cntlOwn. An error 402036 (Cannot Have More Than One Controlling Owner) when trying to avoid the 402066 error and add the new cntlOwn with the existing cntlOwn to be removed afterwards. Is there a way to do this action without having to disable/enable the fincen on the business customer?
we can delete the ctlrOwner BO rec and add the new cntlOwn BO but the old BO rec cannot be an active BO again (undeleted) due to a cntlOwn conflict (402036) when trying to undelete the BO. We have tried to modify the old ctrlOwn BO rec once deleted but have received the same results - error 402066(A Controlling Owner is required....) even tough there is a current cntlOwn.
